# require_once(): Failed to opening required '...' (but the file exists)

Tags: php

When I use require_once I get the following error:

```
"PHP Fatal error: require_once(): Failed to opening required '/Application/Rules/required_file.class.php'"
```

My directory structure is:

- Project

  - Application

    - Rules

      - required_file
  - Public

    - Users

      - file

"file" is where I use `require_once`:

```
require_once('/Application/Rules/required_file.class.php');
```

Why the error? Can anyone help me with the solution?

Comment: Try with require_once('../../Application/Rules/required_file.class.php');

Comment: When you start the path with "/" that means to start at root, And from what I see in the structure you explained the Application directory is not a direct sub-directory of root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you right, you are calling the

```
require_once('/Application/Rules/required_file.class.php');
```

within the `file`? That does *not* work because `require_once` always relates to the *current* folder, as long as you do not use *absolute* paths.

Instead you need to call

```
require_once('../../Application/Rules/required_file.class.php');
```

because the file you want to include is not in the same folder as your `file`.

`../` goes back one folder in the hierarchy.

`../../` therefore goes back from `/Users` to `/Public` and then to `/Project`, form where you then can go to `/Application`.

---

I think this [article](http://bitflop.com/document/95) might explain the difference between *relative* and *absolute* paths quite well.

> The **relative** path points to a file or directory in relation to where the present file is located.
>
> The **absolute** path is the "full path" from the webserver point of view. It is the path that contains the document root. For example /var/www/mydomain.com/.

Answer (score 0):

`/Application/Rules/...` is unix absolute path

either use relative path `../../Application/Rules/...` or proper absolute path

`/var/www/public_html/Project/Application/Rules/...` (unix, example)

or

`C:/wamp/projects/Project/Application/Rules/...` (windows, example)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `../../Application/Rules/required_file.class.php`

Answer (score 0):

use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR will work for windows and unix

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
require_once('Application' .DS. 'Rules' .DS. 'required_file.class.php');
```